# Box model properties (margin, padding) for SVG element. Are they supported?

Tags: svg, margin, padding, css

Is it possible somehow to apply html box model properties to basic shape elements in SVG? For example apply `margin` to `<rect>` element. I found the explanation that it's not possible:

> The display, float and flow properties and all margin, padding, border
>   and background properties can be applied to the top-level svg element
>   but not to child elements within it.

But maybe are there some techniques which make it possible? I'd like to create `<rect>` element with margins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no flow layout inside an svg, so the concept of a margin will have to be done in absolute terms (read: manually).

Explain your use-case in more detail?